# Error after removing 2 columns from 'AspNetUsers' table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

During initial create migration of asp.net identity project, I removed the columns 'PhoneNumber' & 'PhoneNumberConfirmed' from the AspNetUsers table. Now when I attempt to register a new users, I get an error:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'PhoneNumber'.
Invalid column name 'PhoneNumberConfirmed'.]

Source File: \Controllers\AccountController.cs    Line: 155

Line 153:            {
Line 154:                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName =     model.Email, Email = model.Email };
Line 155:                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
Line 156:                if (result.Succeeded)
Line 157:                {
```

I'm guessing I need to update the model and remove the "PhoneNumber' and 'PhoneNumberConfirmed' fields, but I can't locate them in the solution?

Comment: Why not just put the columns back? Were they hurting something?

Comment: Pretty sure the model is part of the Identity.EntityFramework nuget package.  So you don't have the code to change.  In short you need those 2 fields to be there, you can't just delete them.

If you don't want to use that package you can write your own UserStore, UserManager, User Class, etc and design your own database.  Optionally, you could fork the Identity Framework project in git hub, delete the 2 fields from the model, and deploy it to a local Nuget repository, and nuget install it from there (customized).

Comment: Found it, yes those fields are in dependent code.  Here's the project on GitHub.  https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityUser.cs

Comment: Thanks guys. The columns weren't hurting anything, it just seemed unnecessary for them to be there if they weren't being used. Added them back in and everything is working now.